# Jekyll - Generate pages for items in a collection (similar to posts)

Tags: jekyll

I'm making a website/blog that catalogs DIY projects, currently I have each project as a *post*, and recent posts are displayed on the home page.

- What Im trying to do is have a separate page with project/post categories (projects.html). This page lists a *collection* of *post* categories that manually I've made, and will not show any actual posts.
- I would then like these categories/collection items to be generated  into a page that links to a *layout* where I can specify a FOR loop that will display each post specific to that category on the page.

I've tried many ways to generate pages from a collection of .md files as jekyll does for posts but I can't get this working. Is this possible to do? or is there a way to automatically generate an html page for every .md file in a folder?

Here is a link to the page I'm working with. http://happy-swallow.cloudvent.net/

Thanks!

Comment: Did you setup your collections like indicated in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/ ?

Comment: Thanks heaps! I somehow missed this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) and specify to render each file in the collection folder as a page:

- tell Jekyll to render individual collection pages, in  `_config.yml`:

  ```
  collections: 
      my_collection: 
          output: true
  ```
- Then create a folder named `_my_collection` (the folder name must start with an underscore) and every markdown file inside it will have a single page.